# Pandas dataframe join, the calculation process through groupby(Cumulative weighted average)

Tags: python, dataframe, join, cumulative-sum

Thankfully, the contents of the last question were solved well, so I was making a dataset without any problems.(Thank you Ecker!!)

But, there was a new problem.

In the process of calculating the cumulative weighted average through the same process,

When the dataset and type were changed, there were cases where it was not possible to join.

For example, in the dataset below

| firm | date | reviewer | compound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | a | 0.6531 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | b | -0.7213 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | c | -0.3168 |
| A | 2021-01-02 | d | 0.3548 |
| A | 2021-01-02 | e | 0.5783 |
| A | 2021-01-03 | f | 0.4298 |
| A | 2021-01-04 | g | 0.8769 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | h | 0.7895 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | i | -0.4924 |
| B | 2021-01-02 | j | 0.0245 |
| B | 2021-01-02 | k | 0.4982 |
| B | 2021-01-03 | a | 0.1597 |
| B | 2021-01-04 | b | 0.6254 |

‘The compound value’ is a real number (float64) including a decimal point between -1 and 1.

‘The count number’ is the number of reviewers on a specific date.(int64)

I would like to add a column that calculates the cumulative weighted average as shown in the table below.

| firm | date | reviewer | rate | cum_avg_compound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | a | 0.6531 | -0.12833 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | b | -0.7213 | -0.12833 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | c | -0.3168 | -0.12833 |
| A | 2021-01-02 | d | 0.3548 | 0.10962 |
| A | 2021-01-02 | e | 0.5783 | 0.10962 |
| A | 2021-01-03 | f | 0.4298 | 0.162983 |
| A | 2021-01-04 | g | 0.8769 | 0.264971 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | h | 0.7895 | 0.14855 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | i | -0.4924 | 0.14855 |
| B | 2021-01-02 | j | 0.0245 | 0.20495 |
| B | 2021-01-02 | k | 0.4982 | 0.20495 |
| B | 2021-01-03 | a | 0.1597 | 0.1959 |
| B | 2021-01-04 | b | 0.6254 | 0.26748 |

Even if this is converted to the same float64 format, it cannot be combined using join.

The code I tried is as follows.

```
g = (
    df.groupby(['firm', 'date'])['compound']
        .agg(['sum', 'count'])
        .groupby(level='sid').cumsum()
)
df = df.join(
    g ['sum'].div(g_text_emo['count']).rename('cum_avg_compound'),
    on=['firm', 'date'] 
)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you!  Ashutosh Porwal 
Can you tell me how you revised the table?
I think I used the form of stack overflow as it is, but I don't think the table was recognized again.

Comment: I finally know what the problem is.
To start with the conclusion, the code uploaded above was not problematic.
It may be a very small issue, but in the case of "join" dataframes, you need to check whether the data format of the key column of the data frame is the same.
In my case, when checked by print (df.dtypes) code, the perm part appeared as an object type, but
If the dataframe is imported from another file, the format may be recognized differently even if it is the same object type.
So, the solution is to modify the data type again with df ["firm"]=df ["firm"] and so on.astype (str).